# Как получить ссылку на такой фильтр товаров WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

```
function get_product_count()
{

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',

        'post_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['category_id'],
                // Замените 'category-slug' на слаг нужной вам категории
            ),
        ),
        'meta_query' => array(
            
        ),
    );

    $min_price = isset($_POST['min_price']) ? floatval($_POST['min_price']) : 0;
    $max_price = isset($_POST['max_price']) ? floatval($_POST['max_price']) : PHP_FLOAT_MAX;

    array_push(
        $args['meta_query'],
        array(
            'key' => '_price',
            'value' => array($min_price, $max_price),
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        )
    );

    

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    $product_count = $query->found_posts;

    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'count' => $product_count,
            'link' => $query_url,
            'post' => json_encode($_POST),
            'query' => json_encode($args)
        )
    );
```

`$query_url` это должна быть переменная с ссылкой на данный фильтр в формате `home.com/category1/category2/?min_price=10&max_price=20....` Помогите пожалуйста)